# Raspberry Pi camera with opencv broken

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi-zero

I bought a raspberry pi(zero w) camera and ran the opencv example. However, if I specify the frame size, the image is broken. Or not, the image is not broken

```py
import cv2
def vid():
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cap.set(3,200)
    cap.set(4,200)
      if ret:
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
          break
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vid()
```

[image: broken image]

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. Also, RPi cameras have specific width and height parameters that you should be using.

Comment: i edit it, So... should I use it with a fixed width?

Comment: oh i see I changed it to 240x320 and it worked  thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered in the comments